# Problems with a decoupled frontend and php backend in docker-compose

Tags: api, docker, nginx, docker-compose, single-page-application

I've been struggling on a problem with a docker-compose environment where a Single Page Application should talk to a PHP api. Preferrably laravel.

My approach is to have nginx act as a reverve proxy for both.

However, every time i try to hit the /api route, it says file not found. the php-fpm do recieve the request, but it apparantly fails to load the index, even tough it is in the specified folder.

My **docker-compose.yml** looks like this.

```
version: "3.1"

services:

    redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: apitest-redis

    postgres:
      image: postgres:9.6-alpine
      container_name: apitest-postgres
      working_dir: /application/api
      volumes:
        - ./api:/application/api
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=myapiuser
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=2cr34m1ng#n4k3d
        - POSTGRES_DB=test

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: apitest-webserver
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - ./client/dist:/application/dist
          - ./api:/application/api
          - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "8080:80"

    php-fpm:
      build: docker/php-fpm
      container_name: apitest-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application/api
      volumes:
        - ./api:/application/api
        - ./docker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

And my **nginx.conf** looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    client_max_body_size 108M;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;


    root /application;
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        root /application/dist;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        root /application/api/public;
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass apitest-php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```